# While loop with two queues Java

Tags: java, server, queue, client

Good evening. I got this little problem here.Im trying to connect two clients to a server. I made two queues where i put client1 and client2. I got this method here to read from the queue. But im only able to read from one of the queue.

```
NimMessage receiveMessage(Clientconnection client) throws NimServerException {
        NimMessage request = null;

        while (request == null){

            request = (NimMessage) client1.toserver.pollLast(); //read from queue
        }

        //log("\n" + request.toString());
        return request;

}
```

I enter the methodd with this

```
NimMessage request = receiveMessage(client1);
```

But when i want the second client to read the second queue with

```
request = receiveMessage(client2);
```

The receiveMessage method just reads from the client1 queue.
I cant figure out how to add the second queue in the receiveMessage method.

Comment: Maybe just a typo, changing `(NimMessage) client1.toserver.pollLast();` to `(NimMessage) client.toserver.pollLast();` might solve your problem.

Comment: haha yeah it worked thanks^^